# Bootstrap Form - Label and Input Horizontal on same row

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, every time you add a "Label", it creates a new vertical line.  However, what I am trying to achieve is having **two** labels on the same row horizontally.

I have tried working with the "control groups" but have not been able to get it to work the way I want.

Here is essentially what I am trying to achieve (note they are all horizontal):

```
Date                       Start & End Time
 <<input goes here>>       <<start input here>>   <<end input here>>
```

Here's a link to what I am currently stuck with (roughly) [on this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/amimos/1/edit).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [grid](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) system to create two columns

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6"><!-- first col --></div>
    <div class="span6"><!-- second col --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, didn't even realize.